# IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 403: Forbidden

Tags: django, paypal

I am trying to test IPN. Working with django-paypal. What could be wrong.

The URL is working. No errors otherwise...

But when I test this, it says IPN delivery failed and error code is 403,

Answer (score 11):

Same problem on my site. Turns out that when telneting the server, I get the following details concerning the 403:

## Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Hooray, the csrf validation works ;D Now i gotta figure out how to turn it off for this particular form. Hope this hint helps anyone encountering the 403 when using django-paypal.

Comment: Dude! Thank you! I solved this problem before and then forgot about it... he really should update his git!! Just add the `@csrf_exempt` decorator.

Comment: Note that http://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal is a more up-to-date branch and it includes this. As of writing this johnboxall's original branch was last update July 2009.

Comment: adding @csrf_exempt to the view solved my issue. ramdaz should accept this as correct answer. isn't it right?

Comment: fyi, add this: 
     from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your website password protected?  It sounds like paypal is getting a 403 response from your webserver.  Make sure paypal can get to your website without requiring basic auth or something like that.

Comment: Some portions of the site are. But not the page that's been pointed to